# How To update contextMenu after it shows in flex4?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, refresh, contextmenu

I loaded context menu items dynamically and it takes time to load, so context menu appears with default values the first time. But if I right-click again, I see the loaded items.

So can anyone suggest me on how to refresh it or maybe something like how to load the context menu only when the processing is done.

Comment: You might want to consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to help others better understand your problem.

Comment: I believe the context menu only shows up in response to user interaction; and I do not believe it can be modified after it is already up.  But, here are a few things you may consider expanding on: How did you load the context menu items dynamically?  From a remote service?  Why does it take a long time to load?  When do you bring up the context menu?  What are you right clicking on?

Comment: I concur an example would be helpful. But as stated above, once the context menu is displayed, you cannot modify what is currently being shown. Are you loading the items when the user right clicks? Have you tried loading them in advance (like when the app starts)? I think a good compromise would be to add something to the menu that states the items are being loaded, then remove this from the menu when loading is complete.